# Domain Administrators' groups not showing via LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, debian

I have a Debian Squeeze system which is using libnss-ldap to bind to a 2008 Active Directory domain controller to look up users and groups.  Everything works fine, except for some reason anyone who is in the Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins, or Schema Admins group does not get the correct group memberships.  They get only the *Admin group, and no others (unless there are local groups that apply, which do show).

Stranger yet, a "getent group" shows all the correct group memberships for the user, but an "id " or "groups" (when running as the user) doesn't.  We use a domain group for sudo access, and this user is unable to use sudo because it fails to see the group membership.  As soon as the *Admin membership is removed, lookups work correctly.

I suspected maybe this was an AD security feature, but we have FreeBSD systems using nss-ldap on which these users' group memberships resolve correctly. There is nothing in the logs to indicate why these lookups don't return the normal results, and I haven't been able to find anything via Google to help shed light on the situation.  Is anyone else using libnss-ldap in Debian to connect to an AD who can try to confirm this behavior?

Edit: I have confirmed using ldapsearch that the AD is returning the correct results.  I also stopped nscd to make sure it wasn't interfering.  Any user in Domain Admins sees only his primary group, local groups, and Domain Admins.

---

BTW, I think this is the issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976063

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976063 is not related to your problem  This is about the UAC feature.  Since you are running from Debian, UAC is completely out of the picture.  I didn't use libnss-ldap before but there are some commercial product, which I believe doing a better job.  Try downloading a free version of DirecControl from www.centrify.com and see whether it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer was deleted, but the problem was, in fact UAC as described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976063. The issue is that Domain Admins, when UAC is enabled on the DC, actually exist in two states. One that is a member of the domain admins group (i.e., the UAC 'shadow' user) and another that is the normal user. It appears that the DC only returns the former when queried with LDAP. By creating a new group, making that group a member of Domain Admins instead of the accounts themselves, and putting the accounts in the new group, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem also.

I found it eventually about 18 months ago. It is a security feature of Microsoft. There is a service that runs once per hour and removes the admins from the LDAP search. If you do a query as anonymous, you will receive the correct answer for 1 hour.  After one hour you will receive nothing. If you log in as a domain user, you will receive the correct information. That is why you get different results.

I do not at this point remember the service name but I am searching for it now.  I found it originally on Microsoft tech net about 18 months ago, but by now, I don't remember it.

The point was that the only answer to it is

1. Disable that service and it does many other security items so that is not a good idea.
2. Change the LDAP searches to run under a domain user's log in (we have done that on some users)
3. Create a bogus duplicate contact with the same information for each of our admins. This is probably the easiest and quickest, but the most prone to developing wrong information over time.

The rational of this security feature is to hide all domain admins from random anonymous searches so their credentials can't be compromised by an encyclopedia password attack.

Calvin Thomas